# cp Directory target can't be found Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, cp

I'm trying to replace the startup sound on my ubuntu, desktop-login.ogg, with my own, Desktop-login.ogg (located in the Downloads folder) by doing the following:

```
sudo cp desktop-login.ogg.old sudo cp ~/Downloads/Desktop-login.ogg
```

However, this shows up

```
cp: target ‘/home/doughnuts/home/Downloads/Desktop-login.ogg’ is not a directory
```

I thought it was? What's going on?

Comment: Your commands make no sense. `cp` needs an input file and an output file: `sudo cp /path/file.ogg /path2/file2.ogg`.

Answer (score 1):

First:

## You don't need to use `sudo` for copying to your home own directory.

Second:

Your `cp` command is:

```
cp desktop-login.ogg.old sudo cp ~/Downloads/Desktop-login.ogg
```

So, you're trying to copy files named `desktop-login.ogg.old`, `sudo` and `cp` from the current directory, to `~/Downloads/Desktop-login.ogg`. If you tell `cp` to copy multiple files, it will assume the target is a directory. Since the target isn't a directory, it will complain. What you need to use is just:

```
cp desktop-login.ogg.old ~/Downloads/Desktop-login.ogg
```

But from your question, you wanted to copy the latter, to the former. So, you actually need to use:

```
cp ~/Downloads/Desktop-login.ogg desktop-login.ogg.old
```

And if that file is not in your home directory, but in `/usr/share` (or somewhere like that, *then* use `sudo`).

Answer (score 0):

You might be safest to create a backup of the original soundfile first so you can safely revert if you wish. The following single command will accomplish that backup:

```
sudo mv -v /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg \
         /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg_bak
```

Then you can move your own file into place with the following single command:

```
sudo cp -v $HOME/Downloads/desktop-login.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/
```

(Note the lower case on the filename btw). If you wish to revert to your original login sound you can then run:

```
sudo mv -v /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg_bak \
         /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg
```

and all will be back as it was...